# JSP didn't work on GlassFish v.3.1.2.2

Tags: jsp, jsf, glassfish, jstl, jsf-1.2

After migration to GlassFish v.3.1.2.2 I had faced with an incorrect functioning of EL parser. Application fails with exceptions like

> javax.servlet.ServletException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'type'.
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'type'.

Here is my web.xml file web-app part:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation>
```

Here is my glassfish-web.xml part is the same. Here is my faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
```

What am I missing? Is there any dependency conflict? Probably, maybe there is some Tomcat conflict?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your page, not in your application. Looks like an attribute was from `SomeClass` but now is from `String` class type (hint: just read the error message).

Comment: The page works fine on JBoss 4.3 and WebLogic 10.3. Obviously there is dependencies/framework conflict.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with JSF jar files. This is a JSF1.2 app and GlassFish v3 provides JSF 2 libraries (that's the only thing I could notice atm).

Comment: Yep, that's why i uses <useBundleJSF> option in glassfish-web.mxl